# How do I select the day and year of birth from the dropdown after selecting the Month on selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to select the day and year of birth after selecting the month of birth.
Here is what I have tried:

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Month"));
oSelect.selectByIndex(3);

Select oSelect1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Day"));
oSelect1.selectByIndex(12);
```

Comment: Can you please share more details like the HTML of the day and year list boxes, and the error message and trace.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/Overload_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions_MoveToElement.htm ?

Comment: If you already know the format, sent directly the text to the select, like it was a text field.